# Convert List of integers to Hex

Tags: binary, number-bases

I'm doing some OpenCL computing with Mathematica, I have an SHA256 implementation running on my GPU. It returns a list of uints (64bit, Mathematica mistakenly treats these as signed 64bit ints), how do I convert a list of uints like this:

```
{-21538778104198244, -4938185804688833306, -5532891535721358017,
1706758832443728646}
```

Into a hex string something like this:

```
6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b
```

Edit: Here's my current code:

```
    kern = "#ifndef uint32_t
#define uint32_t unsigned int
#endif

#define H0 0x6a09e667
#define H1 0xbb67ae85
#define H2 0x3c6ef372
#define H3 0xa54ff53a
#define H4 0x510e527f
#define H5 0x9b05688c
#define H6 0x1f83d9ab
#define H7 0x5be0cd19


uint rotr(uint x, int n) {
  if (n < 32) return (x >> n) | (x << (32 - n));
  return x;
}

uint ch(uint x, uint y, uint z) {
  return (x & y) ^ (~x & z);
}

uint maj(uint x, uint y, uint z) {
  return (x & y) ^ (x & z) ^ (y & z);
}

uint sigma0(uint x) {
  return rotr(x, 2) ^ rotr(x, 13) ^ rotr(x, 22);
}

uint sigma1(uint x) {
  return rotr(x, 6) ^ rotr(x, 11) ^ rotr(x, 25);
}

uint gamma0(uint x) {
  return rotr(x, 7) ^ rotr(x, 18) ^ (x >> 3);
}

uint gamma1(uint x) {
  return rotr(x, 17) ^ rotr(x, 19) ^ (x >> 10);
}


__kernel void sha256_crypt_kernel(__global uint *data_info,__global \
char *plain_key,  __global uint *digest){
  int t, gid, msg_pad;
  int stop, mmod;
  uint i, ulen, item, total;
  uint W[80], temp, A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,T1,T2;
  uint num_keys = data_info[1];
  int current_pad;

  uint K[64]={
0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5, 0x3956c25b, \
0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3, 0x72be5d74, \
0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc, 0x2de92c6f, \
0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7, 0xc6e00bf3, \
0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13, 0x650a7354, \
0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3, 0xd192e819, \
0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5, 0x391c0cb3, \
0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208, 0x90befffa, \
0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2
};

  msg_pad=0;

  ulen = data_info[2];
  total = ulen%64>=56?2:1 + ulen/64;

//  printf(\"ulen: %u total:%u\\n\", ulen, total);

  digest[0] = H0;
  digest[1] = H1;
  digest[2] = H2;
  digest[3] = H3;
  digest[4] = H4;
  digest[5] = H5;
  digest[6] = H6;
  digest[7] = H7;
  for(item=0; item<total; item++)
  {

    A = digest[0];
    B = digest[1];
    C = digest[2];
    D = digest[3];
    E = digest[4];
    F = digest[5];
    G = digest[6];
    H = digest[7];

#pragma unroll
    for (t = 0; t < 80; t++){
    W[t] = 0x00000000;
    }
    msg_pad=item*64;
    if(ulen > msg_pad)
    {
      current_pad = (ulen-msg_pad)>64?64:(ulen-msg_pad);
    }
    else
    {
      current_pad =-1;    
    }

  //  printf(\"current_pad: %d\\n\",current_pad);
    if(current_pad>0)
    {
      i=current_pad;

      stop =  i/4;
  //    printf(\"i:%d, stop: %d msg_pad:%d\\n\",i,stop, msg_pad);
      for (t = 0 ; t < stop ; t++){
        W[t] = ((uchar)  plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4]) << 24;
        W[t] |= ((uchar) plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4 + 1]) << 16;
        W[t] |= ((uchar) plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4 + 2]) << 8;
        W[t] |= (uchar)  plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4 + 3];
        //printf(\"W[%u]: %u\\n\",t,W[t]);
      }
      mmod = i % 4;
      if ( mmod == 3){
        W[t] = ((uchar)  plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4]) << 24;
        W[t] |= ((uchar) plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4 + 1]) << 16;
        W[t] |= ((uchar) plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4 + 2]) << 8;
        W[t] |=  ((uchar) 0x80) ;
      } else if (mmod == 2) {
        W[t] = ((uchar)  plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4]) << 24;
        W[t] |= ((uchar) plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4 + 1]) << 16;
        W[t] |=  0x8000 ;
      } else if (mmod == 1) {
        W[t] = ((uchar)  plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4]) << 24;
        W[t] |=  0x800000 ;
      } else /*if (mmod == 0)*/ {
        W[t] =  0x80000000 ;
      }
      
      if (current_pad<56)
      {
        W[15] =  ulen*8 ;
        //printf(\"ulen avlue 2 :w[15] :%u\\n\", W[15]);
      }
    }
    else if(current_pad <0)
    {
      if( ulen%64==0)
        W[0]=0x80000000;
      W[15]=ulen*8;
      //printf(\"ulen avlue 3 :w[15] :%u\\n\", W[15]);
    }

    for (t = 0; t < 64; t++) {
      if (t >= 16)
        W[t] = gamma1(W[t - 2]) + W[t - 7] + gamma0(W[t - 15]) + W[t \
- 16];
      T1 = H + sigma1(E) + ch(E, F, G) + K[t] + W[t];
      T2 = sigma0(A) + maj(A, B, C);
      H = G; G = F; F = E; E = D + T1; D = C; C = B; B = A; A = T1 + \
T2;
    }
    digest[0] += A;
    digest[1] += B;
    digest[2] += C;
    digest[3] += D;
    digest[4] += E;
    digest[5] += F;
    digest[6] += G;
    digest[7] += H;

  //  for (t = 0; t < 80; t++)
  //    {
  //    printf(\"W[%d]: %u\\n\",t,W[t]);
  //    }
  }


}"
```

And here's my code using the kernel

```
fun = OpenCLFunctionLoad[kern, 
   "sha256_crypt_kernel", {{"UnsignedByte"}, {"UnsignedByte"}, \
{"UnsignedByte[8]", _ , "Output"}}, {16}];
numhashes = 1;
datainfo = Array[0, {numdatainputs}];
datainfo[[1]] = 64; (* plaintext length constant 64 in source *)
datainfo[[2]] = 1; (* Global work size *)
datainfo[[3]] = 448; (* String length *)
datainfo
(* Why 2048? It's called "kpc" in the source. Don't know why*)
plainkey = ConstantArray[0, 64*2048]; 
hashout = 
  ConstantArray[
   0, {32}];(* Output for hash 4 64bit unsigned integers *)
res = fun[datainfo, plainkey, hashout];
res[[3]]
StringJoin @@ IntegerString[res[[3]], 16]
```

Naturally this results in a hash:

```
"9cb346e987ab3ffe644a59c2ca78bb3f1d9078763837b36a311851da0af17"
```

That is different from Hash

```
Hash["", "SHA256", "HexString"]
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

I realize I'm likely confounding data inout types (opencl vs mathematica) and possibly little/big endian in all this. I don't know how to extract exact types for what Mathematica is handing openCL here.

1. Original OpenCL source code https://github.com/Fruneng/opencl_sha_al_im/blob/master/sha256/sha256.c

Comment: Use [`IntegerString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerString.html)? I am not sure about the mistaken interpretation part. In what format do you received the numbers? How do you import the number into MMA?

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! Maybe `ByteArray` and related functions (like `ByteArrayToString` or `BinaryRead` might be helpful? Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with them so I can't say if they'll work in your case, but it seems related! Also, there may be different ways you can import/read the data right off the bat, which would save you some conversion, but that depends on how exactly Mathematica is getting the data, which isn't clear here.

Answer (score 3):

Define a function to convert a number to a 64-bit hex string while respecting [two's complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement): (thanks to Michael for simplifying!)

```
tohex[x_] := IntegerString[Mod[x, 2^64], 16, 16]
```

Apply to the data and join together:

```
data = {-21538778104198244, -4938185804688833306,
        -5532891535721358017, 1706758832443728646};

StringJoin[tohex /@ data]
(*    "ffb37a986e340b9cbb780a2c9ca544e6b337387678901d3f17afa01d8511a306"    *)
```

Comment: Here's the "bit-twiddling" version of this answer: `With[{b = BitShiftLeft[1, 64]}, IntegerString[FromDigits[BitAnd[{-21538778104198244, -4938185804688833306, -5532891535721358017, 1706758832443728646}, b - 1], b], 16]]`

Comment: Wouldn't `Mod[x, 2^64]` be more efficient than `tc[x]`?

Comment: Yes of course, thanks @MichaelE2!

Comment: In fact, `Mod[x, 2^64] == BitAnd[x, 2^64 - 1]` (though the latter is often faster), so @Michael's suggestion is already incorporated into mine. ;)

Comment: @J.M. I have not found `BitAnd` to be faster than `Mod`. In fact bit operations in Mathematica don't seem as fast as they should be. That seems to be still true in V13.1 on my Mac M1. -- *Update:* Actually, bitwise ops are fast if all the numbers are machine ints. But `2^64 - 1` is not a machine int.